# How to add column to dataset for a quantile on grouped data

Tags: r, quantile

I have data that looks like: (here lot of entries for only 3 different timestamps :00, :01 and :02)

[image]

Target is to calculate 90 percent quantile for `Val` grouped on `timestamp` and add this as a column to `Data` like:

[image]

and finally reduce it to only one line per quantile like:

[image]

It **does work** when taking only the maximum of the group over `timestamp` with:

```
   Data <- Data %>%
     group_by(timestamp) %>%
     slice(which.max(val)) %>%
     ungroup(timestamp)
```

**But** doing it with the 90 percent quantile instead of the max value does not work so far:

```
Data <- Data %>%
  group_by(timestamp) %>%
  slice(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9)) %>%
  ungroup(timestamp)
```

`slice` throws an error:

```
Error in `slice()`:
! Problem while computing indices.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Zeit = 2022-06-02 04:08:05.
Caused by error:
! Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
• Locations: 1
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I add the result of the calculation as a new column to `data`? Tried a lot of things like converting as.double manually, different libraries like tapply, apply, dplyr and so on but was actually not able to get this working.

**EDIT 25.06.2022:**

With `Data <- Data %>% group_by(timestamp) %>% mutate(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9))` the column gets added nevertheless I guess the grouping over the `timestamp` does not work.

(Zeit = timestamp)
(R11_A1Shape1IP = Val)

[image]

[image]

resulting in constantly the same value for the 90 percent quant:

[image]

The timestamp was converted from character to a time format with:

```
Daten[,"Zeit"]<- as.POSIXct(Daten[,"Zeit"],"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz=Sys.timezone())
```

Answer (score 1):

from `?slice`

> "slice() lets you index rows by their (integer) locations. It allows you to select, remove, and duplicate rows."

Are your sure that's what you want? It sounds like you should just use mutate:

```
Data %>%
  group_by(timestamp) %>%
  mutate(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   timestamp [1]
  timestamp                Val quant90
  <chr>                  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 01.06.2022 23:00:00 -0.00438   0.869
2 01.06.2022 23:00:00 -0.00750   0.869
3 01.06.2022 23:00:00  1.23      0.869
4 01.06.2022 23:00:00  0.0155    0.869
```

Or to return one row per group:

```
Data %>%
  group_by(timestamp) %>%
  summarize(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  timestamp           quant90
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 01.06.2022 23:00:00   0.869
```

Comment: `Data` has about 60 lines per second. What slice did when I tried to keep the maximum value is that it reduced the group (all entries to that second) to just one line with the maximum `Val` (with grouping over time and `slice(which.max(Val))`). Now I try to do the same thing just returning the 90 percent intervall for that groups (exact timestamp to the second) Values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to do. Can you post a table with your desired output that includes more than one timestamp value, as an edit to your original question? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, just edited the original post to better explain the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Have you tried using the second code chunk in my answer? I believe it does exactly what is in your expected output. If I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but summarize is just printing the result but not adding the column the the existing DataSet or did I miss something?

Comment: `Data <- Data %>% group_by(timestamp) %>% mutate(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9))` or `newData <- Data %>% group_by(timestamp) %>% summarize(quant90 = quantile(Val, probs = 0.9))`

Comment: Hi @Skaqqs thank you! It now adds a new column for quant90 but it's just one value. Guess there is something going wrong with the grouping :-/ Maybe a final idea on that? (I edited the original Post again)